# Is there a way to calculate $E\left[\mathrm{sgn}(X)X^n\right]$ if I don't know the pdf for $X$ but I do know the characteristic function?

Tags: statistics, expected-value, characteristic-functions

I need to calculate $E\left[\mathrm{sgn}(X)X^n\right]$, where $\mathrm{sgn}(X)$ denotes the sign of the random variable $X$. I don't know the pdf for $X$, so I can't do the calculation directly. I know the characteristic function, so I have the moments, but I'm not sure if it's possible to handle the sign function.

My first thought was to write $\mathrm{sgn}(X) = \lim_{k\to\infty}\tanh(kX)$, then expand tanh as a Taylor series in $X$, resum, and take the limit. However, resumming the resulting series isn't possible, because the moments are extremely messy.

Is there something obvious I'm missing here, or is my task impossible?

Comment: Characteristic function does not give you the moments of the function. If the moment generating function exists and is well defined in a neighbourhood around $0$, then you have that all absolute moments exists of all orders. Note that characteristic function is always well defined for any random variable (which is finite almost surely)

Comment: What is the characteristic function?